# Reshape Dataframe with index containing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

Good Evening.
I need help for a question in Python to reshape a Dataframe.

I am trying to reshape a dataframe like this:

df

| id | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | aa |
| 1 | b | bb |
| 2 | a | aa |
| 2 | b | bb |
| 3 | a | aa |
| 3 | b | bb |

For this:

df_result

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | bb |
| 2 | aa | aa |
| 3 | bb | bb |

I tried with:

```
df.pivot(index='id', columns = 'question', values = 'answer')
```

But return : Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

I tried with `pandas.melt` and `pandas.pivot_table`, but both went wrong.

How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `aggfunc` parameter to `pivot_table` but you have to make a choice on how to treat duplicate values. Below, I choose `first`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='question', values='answer', aggfunc='first')

question   a   b
id
1         aa  bb
2         aa  bb
3         aa  bb
```

Comment: Thanks!
I tried and it worked, now I'm going to check if the data is ok.

Comment: @MClaver89. Did you have time to check answer on your data?